# Why can't function `Maximize` find the maximum position exactly?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

```
f[x_, y_] := -(x^4 + 3*y^4 - 0.2*Cos[3*π*x] - 
     0.4*Cos[4*π*y] + 0.6);
Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.5], Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}, Axes -> True]
Maximize[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]]
FindMaximum[{f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ 
   Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}, {x, y}]
```

The above code returns: `{-0.338019355,{x->-0.612594795,y->-0.478888849}}`

Although the value of $f[0, 0] \approx 0 $ is significantly larger than `-0.338019355`, it has not been found.

Comment: NMaximize[f[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]] gives the answer.

Comment: There is a local maximum at the point `{x->-0.612594795,y->-0.478888849}`. As per the documentation, "If *f* and *cons* are linear or polynomial, `Maximize` will always find a global maximum.", implying that if these are *not* the case, then `Maximize` may find non-global local maximum instead. You could used `FindMaximum`, which finds local maxima, but you can specify an initial guess which will allow you to find other local maxima and perhaps the global maximum.

Comment: the presence of approximate values in the input very likely causes `Maximize` to farm it out to `NMaximize`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on @march 's comment as stated in the online documentation `FindMaximum` finds local maximums so good starting values are important especially in a function like what you're using that has several local maximums.

```
f[x_, y_] := -(x^4 + 3*y^4 - 0.2*Cos[3*\[Pi]*x] - 0.4*Cos[4*\[Pi]*y] + 0.6);

sol1 = FindMaximum[{f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}, {{x, 1}, {y, 1}}]
sol2 = FindMaximum[{f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}, {{x, 0.1}, {y, 0.1}}]
sol3 = FindMaximum[{f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}, {{x, 0.5}, {y, 0.5}}]

startStop = {{{1, 1}, {x, y} /. sol1[[2]]},
   {{0.1, 0.1}, {x, y} /. sol2[[2]]},
   {{0.5, 0.5}, {x, y} /. sol3[[2]]}};
Show[ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Contours -> 100,
  PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotRangeClipping -> False],
 ListPlot[startStop, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Black],
 ListPlot[{#} & /@ Flatten[startStop, 1], 
  PlotStyle -> {{Green, PointSize[0.02]}, {Red, PointSize[0.02]}},
  PlotLegends -> {"Start", "Stop"}]]
```

[image: Function and local maximums]

Answer (score 3):

`Rationalize` helps:

```
  f[x_, y_] = Rationalize[-(x^4 + 3*y^4 - 0.2*Cos[3*π*x] - 0.4*Cos[4*π*y] + 0.6),0];
  Maximize[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]]
  {0, {x -> 0, y -> 0}}
```